# laravel when i run queue:work inside laravel php file the job table did not cleared

Tags: php, laravel

hello everyone i have project on laravel 9 everything working so good so far
i have queue job and when i do this
[image]
its running good and it clear job table after finsh now my problem is when  i run php artisan queue:work inside php file like this

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
class General_controller extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        Artisan::call('queue:work');
    }
}
```

its working but it didnot clear the job table
so when i run the command again it did the same job again and again ect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the queue:work artisan command inside a controller method. When you call the queue:work command, it starts a worker that listens for new jobs on the queue and processes them. It doesn't make sense to run this from within a controller method because it is intended to be a long-running process that listens for jobs and handles them as they come in.

In your case, if you want to process the queue when calling the test method, you can add **--once** to the queue:work command. This will process only the next job on the queue and then exit.
*Note that this should still be used with caution and is not the recommended way of processing queued jobs. The best practice is to have a queue worker running in the background on your server.*

Plus: if you are using artisan serve on localhost. It only has a single thread and cannot start another command from within a request.